# Rust ffi wrapper for barcode scanning library

Tags: beginner, rust, wrapper, ffi

I'm the maintainer of the [zxing-cpp](https://github.com/zxing-cpp/zxing-cpp) library, a barcode image processing library written in C++. I recently decided to invest in a Rust wrapper library/crate that is now on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/zxing-cpp). It is basically a very simple API: a bunch of enums, 4 structs/classes to pass parameters in/out and one static function:

```
pub fn read_barcodes<'a>(
    image: impl TryInto<ImageView<'a>>,
    opts: impl AsRef<ReaderOptions>
) -> Result<Vec<Barcode>, Error>
```

A minimal use case scenario looks like this:

> ```
>   let image = image::open("some-image-file.jpg")?;
>   let opts = ReaderOptions::default()
>       .formats(BarcodeFormat::QRCode | BarcodeFormat::LinearCodes)
>       .try_invert(false);
>
>   let barcodes = read_barcodes(&image, &opts)?;
>
>   for barcode in barcodes {
>       println!("{}: {}", barcode.format(), barcode.text());
>   }
> ```

And here is the actual code

```
/*
* Copyright 2024 Axel Waggershauser
*/
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

#![allow(unused_unsafe)]
#![allow(clippy::useless_transmute)]
#![allow(clippy::redundant_closure_call)]

mod tests;

#[allow(dead_code)]
#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
mod bindings {
    include!("bindings.rs");
}

use bindings::*;

use flagset::{flags, FlagSet};
use paste::paste;
use std::ffi::{c_char, c_int, c_uint, c_void, CStr, CString};
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
use std::io::ErrorKind;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::mem::transmute;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub type Error = std::io::Error;

fn c2r_str(str: *mut c_char) -> String {
    let mut res = String::new();
    if !str.is_null() {
        unsafe { res = CStr::from_ptr(str).to_string_lossy().to_string() };
        unsafe { zxing_free(str as *mut c_void) };
    }
    res
}

fn c2r_vec(buf: *mut u8, len: c_int) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut res = Vec::<u8>::new();
    if !buf.is_null() && len > 0 {
        unsafe { res = std::slice::from_raw_parts(buf, len as usize).to_vec() };
        unsafe { zxing_free(buf as *mut c_void) };
    }
    res
}

fn last_error() -> Error {
    match unsafe { zxing_LastErrorMsg().as_mut() } {
        None => panic!("Internal error: zxing_LastErrorMsg() returned NULL"),
        Some(error) => Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidInput, c2r_str(error)),
    }
}

macro_rules! last_error_or {
    ($expr:expr) => {
        match unsafe { zxing_LastErrorMsg().as_mut() } {
            None => Ok($expr),
            Some(error) => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidInput, c2r_str(error))),
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! make_zxing_enum {
    ($name:ident { $($field:ident),* }) => {
        #[repr(u32)]
        #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
        pub enum $name {
            $($field = paste! { [<zxing_ $name _ $field>] },)*
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! make_zxing_flags {
    ($name:ident { $($field:ident),* }) => {
        flags! {
            #[repr(u32)]
            pub enum $name: c_uint {
                $($field = paste! { [<zxing_ $name _ $field>] },)*
            }
        }
    }
}
#[rustfmt::skip] // workaround for broken #[rustfmt::skip::macros(make_zxing_enum)]
make_zxing_enum!(ImageFormat { Lum, RGB, RGBX });
#[rustfmt::skip]
make_zxing_enum!(ContentType { Text, Binary, Mixed, GS1, ISO15434, UnknownECI });
#[rustfmt::skip]
make_zxing_enum!(Binarizer { LocalAverage, GlobalHistogram, FixedThreshold, BoolCast });
#[rustfmt::skip]
make_zxing_enum!(TextMode { Plain, ECI, HRI, Hex, Escaped });
#[rustfmt::skip]
make_zxing_enum!(EanAddOnSymbol { Ignore, Read, Require });

#[rustfmt::skip]
make_zxing_flags!(BarcodeFormat {
    None, Aztec, Codabar, Code39, Code93, Code128, DataBar, DataBarExpanded, DataMatrix, EAN8, EAN13, ITF,
    MaxiCode, PDF417, QRCode, UPCA, UPCE, MicroQRCode, RMQRCode, DXFilmEdge, LinearCodes, MatrixCodes, Any
});

pub type BarcodeFormats = FlagSet<BarcodeFormat>;

impl Display for BarcodeFormat {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", unsafe { c2r_str(zxing_BarcodeFormatToString(BarcodeFormats::from(*self).bits())) })
    }
}

impl Display for ContentType {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", unsafe { c2r_str(zxing_ContentTypeToString(transmute(*self))) })
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct ImageViewOwner<'a>(*mut zxing_ImageView, PhantomData<&'a u8>);

impl Drop for ImageViewOwner<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { zxing_ImageView_delete(self.0) }
    }
}
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct ImageView<'a>(Rc<ImageViewOwner<'a>>);

impl<'a> From<&'a ImageView<'a>> for ImageView<'a> {
    fn from(img: &'a ImageView) -> Self {
        img.clone()
    }
}

impl<'a> ImageView<'a> {
    fn try_into_int<T: TryInto<c_int>>(val: T) -> Result<c_int, Error> {
        val.try_into()
            .map_err(|_| Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidInput, "Could not convert Integer into c_int."))
    }

    /// Constructs an ImageView from a raw pointer and the width/height (in pixels)
    /// and row_stride/pix_stride (in bytes).
    ///
    /// # Safety
    ///
    /// The memory gets accessed inside the c++ library at random places between
    /// `ptr` and `ptr + height * row_stride` or `ptr + width * pix_stride`.
    /// Note that both the stride values could be negative, e.g. if the image
    /// view is rotated.
    pub unsafe fn from_ptr<T: TryInto<c_int>, U: TryInto<c_int>>(
        ptr: *const u8,
        width: T,
        height: T,
        format: ImageFormat,
        row_stride: U,
        pix_stride: U,
    ) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let iv = zxing_ImageView_new(
            ptr,
            Self::try_into_int(width)?,
            Self::try_into_int(height)?,
            format as zxing_ImageFormat,
            Self::try_into_int(row_stride)?,
            Self::try_into_int(pix_stride)?,
        );
        if iv.is_null() {
            Err(last_error())
        } else {
            Ok(ImageView(Rc::new(ImageViewOwner(iv, PhantomData))))
        }
    }

    pub fn from_slice<T: TryInto<c_int>>(data: &'a [u8], width: T, height: T, format: ImageFormat) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        unsafe {
            let iv = zxing_ImageView_new_checked(
                data.as_ptr(),
                data.len() as c_int,
                Self::try_into_int(width)?,
                Self::try_into_int(height)?,
                format as zxing_ImageFormat,
                0,
                0,
            );
            if iv.is_null() {
                Err(last_error())
            } else {
                Ok(ImageView(Rc::new(ImageViewOwner(iv, PhantomData))))
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(feature = "image")]
use image;

#[cfg(feature = "image")]
impl<'a> From<&'a image::GrayImage> for ImageView<'a> {
    fn from(img: &'a image::GrayImage) -> Self {
        ImageView::from_slice(img.as_ref(), img.width(), img.height(), ImageFormat::Lum).unwrap()
    }
}

#[cfg(feature = "image")]
impl<'a> TryFrom<&'a image::DynamicImage> for ImageView<'a> {
    type Error = Error;

    fn try_from(img: &'a image::DynamicImage) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let format = match img {
            image::DynamicImage::ImageLuma8(_) => Some(ImageFormat::Lum),
            image::DynamicImage::ImageRgb8(_) => Some(ImageFormat::RGB),
            image::DynamicImage::ImageRgba8(_) => Some(ImageFormat::RGBX),
            _ => None,
        };
        match format {
            Some(format) => Ok(ImageView::from_slice(img.as_bytes(), img.width(), img.height(), format)?),
            None => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidInput, "Invalid image format (must be either luma8|rgb8|rgba8)")),
        }
    }
}

pub struct ReaderOptions(*mut zxing_ReaderOptions);

impl Drop for ReaderOptions {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { zxing_ReaderOptions_delete(self.0) }
    }
}

impl Default for ReaderOptions {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}

impl AsRef<ReaderOptions> for ReaderOptions {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &ReaderOptions {
        self
    }
}

macro_rules! property {
    ($name:ident, $type:ty) => {
        pub fn $name(self, v: impl Into<$type>) -> Self {
            paste! { unsafe { [<zxing_ReaderOptions_set $name:camel>](self.0, transmute(v.into())) } };
            self
        }

        paste! {
            pub fn [<set_ $name>](&mut self, v : impl Into<$type>) -> &mut Self {
                unsafe { [<zxing_ReaderOptions_set $name:camel>](self.0, transmute(v.into())) };
                self
            }

            pub fn [<get_ $name>](&self) -> $type {
                unsafe { transmute([<zxing_ReaderOptions_get $name:camel>](self.0)) }
            }
        }
    };
}

impl ReaderOptions {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        unsafe { ReaderOptions(zxing_ReaderOptions_new()) }
    }

    property!(try_harder, bool);
    property!(try_rotate, bool);
    property!(try_invert, bool);
    property!(try_downscale, bool);
    property!(is_pure, bool);
    property!(return_errors, bool);
    property!(formats, BarcodeFormats);
    property!(text_mode, TextMode);
    property!(binarizer, Binarizer);
    property!(ean_add_on_symbol, EanAddOnSymbol);
    property!(max_number_of_symbols, i32);
    property!(min_line_count, i32);
}

pub struct Barcode(*mut zxing_Barcode);

impl Drop for Barcode {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { zxing_Barcode_delete(self.0) }
    }
}

macro_rules! getter {
    ($r_name:ident, $c_name:ident, $conv:expr, $type:ty) => {
        pub fn $r_name(&self) -> $type {
            paste! { unsafe { $conv([<zxing_Barcode_ $c_name>](self.0)) } }
        }
    };
}

impl Barcode {
    getter!(is_valid, isValid, transmute, bool);
    getter!(format, format, (|f| BarcodeFormats::new(f).unwrap().into_iter().last().unwrap()), BarcodeFormat);
    getter!(content_type, contentType, transmute, ContentType);
    getter!(text, text, c2r_str, String);
    getter!(ec_level, ecLevel, c2r_str, String);
    getter!(error_message, errorMsg, c2r_str, String);
    getter!(symbology_identifier, symbologyIdentifier, c2r_str, String);
    getter!(orientation, orientation, transmute, i32);
    getter!(has_eci, hasECI, transmute, bool);
    getter!(is_inverted, isInverted, transmute, bool);
    getter!(is_mirrored, isMirrored, transmute, bool);
    getter!(line_count, lineCount, transmute, i32);

    pub fn bytes(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut len: c_int = 0;
        unsafe { c2r_vec(zxing_Barcode_bytes(self.0, &mut len), len) }
    }
}

pub fn read_barcodes<'a>(image: impl TryInto<ImageView<'a>>, opts: impl AsRef<ReaderOptions>) -> Result<Vec<Barcode>, Error> {
    let iv_: ImageView = image
        .try_into()
        .map_err(|_| Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidInput, "Failed to image.try_into::<ImageView>()"))?;
    unsafe {
        let results = zxing_ReadBarcodes((iv_.0).0, opts.as_ref().0);
        if !results.is_null() {
            let size = zxing_Barcodes_size(results);
            let mut vec = Vec::<Barcode>::with_capacity(size as usize);
            for i in 0..size {
                vec.push(Barcode(zxing_Barcodes_move(results, i)));
            }
            zxing_Barcodes_delete(results);
            Ok(vec)
        } else {
            Err(last_error())
        }
    }
}
```

Things that are specifically debatable as far as I can see:

- the use of `TryInto` trait for the `image` parameter which is supposed to allow passing a multitude of different image like objects directly without first instantiating the `ImageView` adapter class explicitly.
- the use of the `AsRef` trait for the `options` parameter so that we can pass both an object and a reference to one.
- the use of `pub type Error = std::io::Error;`

I'm looking for any suggestions that would make this a 'better' and/or more idiomatic Rust API before I set something in stone. The internals like the helper macros are not of importance to me now as they can be changed anytime.